# Getting insufficient balance error while trying 'anchor deploy' , but I have enough fund in my wallet. How to solve this?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, solana-wallet-adapter, anchor-client, anchor-spl

> Deploying workspace: http://localhost:8899
> Upgrade authority: /home/dev_roy/.config/solana/id.json
> Deploying program "basic-1"...
> Program path: /home/dev_roy/User/solana-wallet-setup/anchor/examples/tutorial/basic-1/target/deploy/basic_1.so...
> =============================================================================
> Recover the intermediate account's ephemeral keypair file with
> `solana-keygen recover` and the following 12-word seed phrase:
> =============================================================================
> miracle harbor rookie oxygen ready shed nest hen romance magnet dismiss cigar
> =============================================================================
> To resume a deploy, pass the recovered keypair as the
> [BUFFER_SIGNER] to `solana program deploy` or `solana program write-buffer'. Or to recover the account's lamports, pass it as the [BUFFER_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] argument to` solana program close`.
> =============================================================================
> Error: Account eJckR6THvr2bBtHKbuLnnxcxXxKHoqA3jd8buYdtg8U has insufficient funds for spend (1.53190296 SOL) + fee (0.00111 SOL)
> There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.

when checking my account balance it is showing

3 SOL

which is greater than the amount required for the transaction.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

You might not be aligned correctly with what your local solana config is setup as. Could you open your terminal and type in "solana config get" and see what it says? The problem here is often the developer is connected to mainnet when they want devnet, or the location of their file system wallet is mismatched here.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the `[provider]` section in your Anchor.toml file specifies `cluster = "Localnet"`. If it doesn't, Anchor might be trying to deploy against a different cluster that isn't localnet where you have sol.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're using different wallets. Try logging the address of the wallet you might be using in the terminal. Use the following command
```solana address``
After that log the publickkey of the keypair you're using to deploy the program.
Lastly, also make sure you're on the same network(Devnet/Mainnet etc)